# Windows Phone 7 Development Delay on Buttons

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I have created a button in C# for Windows phone 7 development. It contains an animation and when clicked I want the animation to be shown, and then for the button to navigate to the next page.

Using `Thread.Sleep(4000)` just crashes the application and I was wondering how I go about this.

Is there a way to delay the navigate code?

```
private void batnballBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/PictureGame.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably the animation is a `Storyboard`. You can navigate within the Storyboard's `Completed` event.

```
myStoryboard.Completed += (s, e) =>
{
    myStoryboard.Stop();        
    NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/PictureGame.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
};
```

This way you don't need to predict how long the animation will take, making the code more reusable, and you don't have to worry about dealing with multiple threads manually.

Answer (score 1):

Use a thread for that:

http://techkn0w.wordpress.com/2012/04/18/using-a-background-thread-in-windows-phone-7-wp7/

You're stopping the UI thread that's why the button is freeze.

There is only one thread responsible for managing the UI, so, if you block it when doing lengthy operations or making it sleep the UI process management is freezed until that work has finished.

Something like this:

```
private void batnballBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((WaitCallback)delegate(object state)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(4000);

            this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)delegate
            {
                NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/PictureGame.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
            });
        });
}
```